# SQL Server 2000: How to get top 10 for each distinct field. A loop Maybe?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table

```
MyTable
  ID
  MessageType
  MessageDate
  MessageBody
```

The table is a few million rows but there are only 100 unique MessageType in it.

What I need is a sample of each MessageType (must include at least MessageType and MessageBody), but I can't do a  `DISTINCT` as that only gets me the MessageType column.

I am thinking something like

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE MessageType IN (SELECT DISTINCT MessageType FROM MyTable)
```

I know this doesn't work as it just me the top 5, but I am not sure how to make SQL loop through this.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Much easier in later versions with `CROSS APPLY` or `ROW_NUMBER`. `TOP` ordered by what?

Comment: I can import the table into a SQL 2008 DB as this is a one time report. As for ordered by, that doesn't matter as I just need 5 of each MessageType.

Comment: Can I ask that the [sql-server-2000] tag be removed from this, as none of the answers actually apply to that version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Row_Number version

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT   ID,
  MessageType,
  MessageDate,
  MessageBody,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MessageType ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN
FROM MyTable
)
SELECT   ID,
  MessageType,
  MessageDate,
  MessageBody
FROM cte 
WHERE RN <=5
```

The `CROSS APPLY` version

```
WITH m1 AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT MessageType
FROM MyTable
)

SELECT m2.*
FROM  m1
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT TOP 5 *
 FROM MyTable m2
 WHERE m2.MessageType = m1.MessageType
 ) m2
```

Comment: Good stuff. I was going to add a second version that may be more efficient for your data distribution but my internet connection started playing up!

Answer (score 2):

Martin, if I'm reading your answer correctly, I think what you will produce is 5 samples of each message.  Marc_s just wants one sample from each message.

I think what you need is:

```
SELECT  ID,
        MessageType,
        MessageDate
FROM (
    SELECT ID,
           MessageType,
           MessageDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MessageType, ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS RN
       -- I am using NewID() because it will produce a nice random sampling, 
       -- but Mark's SELECT(0) will be faster.
    FROM   MyTable
    ) sampling
WHERE RN =1
```

Comment: +1 because I can see why you would think that but the title indicates they do want more than the top 1 per group and this was clarified in the comments.